# What would the properties of a particle be that would allow light to orbit it?

Tags: particle-physics, speed-of-light, orbital-motion

What would the properties of a particle be that would allow light to orbit it?

Light travels fast. *Really* fast. Almost to the point where we consider that it's instantaneous, and moves only in a straight line.

We know that's not true though. Light can be influenced in such a way so as to cause it to change course. "Bend" if you will.

Black holes influence light strongly enough as to cause the light to be pulled in without escaping. (at least, as far as we know. right?)

This gives me the fundamental basis for thinking that it would be possible to influence light enough to allow it to orbit a particle. I'm curious if anyone has an idea of what properties a particle like this would have, how it could be described, and whether or not it could exist in our physical reality.

Comment: similar, not a duplicate.

Comment: If you edit the question to address what makes it different from that other one, I'll be happy to reopen it.

Comment: Going to redo the question to better explain what I'm trying to ask. Thanks.